# ¿Como acceder a un objecto por clase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Este es mi fragmento de codigo que me genera error.

```
boton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".boton boton-rojo")
boton[0].click()
```

Aqui esta el objecto html:

```
<div class="boton boton-rojo"><a href="https://******.*****.com.co/iModelWeb/vista/cotizar/cotizar.jsf?&amp;nit=9007123621&amp;nombreusuario=******&amp;agente=****&amp;cod_agt=*****&amp;agentev=98772&amp;usuario=******&amp;cod_cia=&amp;cia=&amp;token=******.BFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DD&amp;idPerfil=EI&amp;tokenNew=TECAASES.BFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DDBFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DD&amp;nombBreCrumOfiVirt=Cotizar%20-%20Emitir" onclick="cmdRegistrarNavegacion([{name:'paramId', value:'OPT_ATG_AUTOGES_II_COTIZAR_HOME'},{name:'paramNombre', value:'Cotizar - Emitir'},{name:'paramTipo', value:'W'},{name:'paramUrl', value:'https://cotiza.mapfre.com.co/iModelWeb/vista/cotizar/cotizar.jsf?&amp;nit=9007123621&amp;nombreusuario=9007123621&amp;agente=98772&amp;cod_agt=98772&amp;agentev=98772&amp;usuario=TECAASES&amp;cod_cia=&amp;cia=&amp;token=TECAASES.BFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DD&amp;idPerfil=EI&amp;tokenNew=TECAASES.BFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DDBFE96A5FCF41773D22A8D88E227160DD&amp;nombBreCrumOfiVirt=Cotizar - Emitir'}]);" target="_blank">
                            <img src="../../resources/images/btn-cotizadores.png"></a>
                    </div>
```

Este es el error que me genera:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Una
ble to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".boton boton-rojo"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87a
f1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Necesita clickear el primer objecto de esa clase, en el html solo hay dos.
Utilizo el driver de chrome alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: No es necesario coloca python o selenium en el titulo, para ello estan los tags.

Comment: Ok, Gracias por la correción.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que ese elemento existe o está completamente cargado en el DOM cuando lanzas la búsqueda? ¿Tienes algún wait implícito o explícito para asegurarte que el elemento está disponible antes del find? ¿Se encuentra dentro de un frame/iframe?

Comment: coloque un time de 5 segundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede emplear `find_elements_by_class_name` para encontrar los elementos en su documento por medio de su clase pero se le pasará solo la clase `boton-rojo` , tener cuidado con `elements` en plural  ya que también existe una opción `find_element_by_class_name` en singular para obtener un solo elemento.

**DOM**

```
<div class="boton boton-rojo">Bton1</div>

<div class="boton boton-rojo">Bton 2</div>
```

**Python**

```
boton = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("boton-rojo")
print boton[0].text;
print boton[1].text;

boton[0].click()
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de indicar el voto negativo, pero en este caso te lo explicare, tu respuesta es la misma del otro usuario, tu respuesta no contribuye en nada nuevo, asi que eso la invalida.

Comment: @eyllanesc `find_elements_by_class_name`  **plural** es muy diferente a singular. y **No** , para nada es la misma.  Saludos y gracias por comentar.

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta añadiendo esa informacion porque aunque lo leas uno observara que es lo mismo, ademas que no puedo quitar mi downvote si no lo editas :P

Comment: Uno puede usar una funcion y decir para encontrar los elementos, esa frase es ambigua.

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar algo como esto:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p class="content">Site content goes here.</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Para acceder al elemento `p` con clase `content`:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('content')
```

[Aca puedes encontrar mas info de find_element_by_class_name](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name)